# Dependent resources in nested react-router Redux Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

If I have a upper level route that fetches the user, and a nested route that makes calls that reference the order, what is the most reduxy way to ensure order of operations?

```
<Route path="/" component={Authenticated}>
  <Route path="/things" component={ListThingsBelongingToUser} />
</Route>
```

In this example, I need Authenticated to have retrieved a user and added it to the state before ListThingsBelongingToUser tries to retrieve stuff for the user.

I read that onEnter is a good way to do this, but am I supposed (allowed?) to mutate state or dispatch an action in onEnter? Would onEnter let me wait for the user to be added to state before continuing on?

Answer (score 0):

The nested route was already waiting on the parent route, I was just looking at the wrong variable :-(